# how to get the number of integer in a file with empty space in it

Tags: c

number.txt

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

For instance, I have the above text file. I would like to get the number of integer in the file (which is 14 in this case), and pass every integer into an array.

what I did is

```
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
while ( 1 )
{
   int c = fgetc( fp );
   if ( c == EOF || c == '\n' )
   {
      if ( c == EOF ) break;
   }
   else if(c ==' ')
   {
       ++count;
       --count;
   }
   else
   {

      ++count;
      arr[i] = c-48; // This line give me the wrong number so I subtract it by 48
      ++i;
   }
}
```

In the case, the count will only get the correct value when there is no double digits number in the file(such as 10 11 12 13). Otherwise, it does not work.

I also tried to use fscanf to store every integer in an array, then get the length of the array. That does not work since I have to define the length of the array first and there is no way I can do that.

My question is how to deal with the double digits number in the file in order to get the right value. Is there a better to do that? Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why bother with an array? Just keep reading `%d` via `fscanf` until it reports no valid conversion, each time bumping a counter on success. The value read can just be thrown away.

Comment: wouldn't the count of the above file be 15?

Comment: `++count; /* increment count */` followed by
       `--count; /* decrement count */` ... what?

Comment: When we're counting from 1 to 100 and we run out of single-digit numbers, what do we do to get to 10? We add 1 to the tens column instead, right? Why is it called the tens column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just read the integers with `fscanf()`, and every time a number is found, increment a counter.

Something as simple as this could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    int num;
    size_t count = 0;

    fp = fopen("somenumbers.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) == 1) {
        count++;
    }

    printf("number of digits = %zu\n", count);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just one question. what is the difference between size_t count =0 and int count = 0?

Comment: @zhangdi You can just replace `count` with `int`. `size_t` just means an unsigned integer data type.